# Tymon\JWTAuth::toUser error: A token is required

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

I have a Larvel API that uses Tymon\JWTAuth to authenticate the user.

It is working fine.

For some reasons I have also a non-guarded route  in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('myroute', 'MyController@mymethod');
```

The code of MyController@mymethod is the following:

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->input('token'));

// I tried also this:
// JWTAuth::setToken($request->input('token'));
// $user = JWTAuth::authenticate();
```

And I call the route using this url in the browser: `/myroute?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci....`

The problem is that I have an exception in JWT.php:

> Tymon \ JWTAuth \ Exceptions \ JWTException
>   A token is required

JWT.php

```
protected function requireToken()
{
    if (! $this->token) {
        throw new JWTException('A token is required');
    }
}
```

How can I decode the token that is passed as URL parameter and not in the header of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this code:

```
use Namshi\JOSE\SimpleJWS;

$secret = config('jwt.secret');
$jws = SimpleJWS::load($token);
if (!$jws->isValid($secret)) {
   return response()->json([], 401); // unauthorized
} 
$payload = $jws->getPayload();
$account = Account::find($payload["account"]["id"]);
```

However I would have preferred to use directly JWTAuth

Comment: how do you get user object from this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```php
$user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->input('token'));
```

Use

```php
$user = $this->jwt->User();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jwt-auth dev, the toUser method in old version will drop the error like above, try this:

```
// Get the currently authenticated user
$user = auth()->user();
```

If the user is not then authenticated, then null will be returned.

Comment: OP is asking how they can decode `$token` when sending as query parameters