# "A token is required" in JWT Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tymon-jwt

I was trying to get the details of logged in user got this link

```
 use JWTAuth;
 $user=JWTAuth::toUser($token);
```

i tried this also `$user = auth()->user();` getting NULL

$token variable is same which i have i browser local storage.

this link i found but this is not working in my case.

> [Tymon\JWTAuth::toUser error: A token is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843841/tymon-jwtauthtouser-error-a-token-is-required)

Comment: I'm using passport instead of JWT, but in my case to get the current user I just need to do `$request->user()` or `auth('api')->user`

Comment: @Luciano: But i'm using JWT i want to get details of logged in user

Comment: Do you have `JWT_SECRET` in `.env`?

Comment: @S.Farooq Yes i have JWT_SECRET in my env

Comment: Did you try what I've commented to see if you get the currently logged-in user? Both `$request->user()` and `auth('api')->user` should retrieve User model for the one who is running the request

Comment: @Luciano: Yes i have tried NULL is being returned